# How can I remove specific index from list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to figure out how to remove specific index from list, but I don't know how to fix my problem. Can someone help me to solve this?

First, I have to get some numbers from users using input.

```
numbers = int(input("input any numbers: "))
list_num = list(numbers)
```

Second, if list_num[0] == 1, remove that element.

Third, if  list_num[i+1] == list_num[i], remove list_num[i+1].

So, if the initial list goes like this: `list_num = [1,2,7,8,13,20,21]`,

the final list will be `list_num = [2,7,13,20]`

This is the program to be fixed:

```
 numbers = int(input("input any numbers:"))
 list_num = list(numbers)
 if list_num[0] ==1:
    list_num.remove(num[0])
 for i in range(1,len(list_num)-1, 1):
    if list_num[i] = list_num[i+1] -1:
         list_num.remove(num[i+1])
 print(list_num)
```

Comment: Note that removing an item from a list whilst iterating through it will cause problems. It is best to use a list comprehension, or some other method to build a new list with elements from the old one. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) question.

Comment: Just for fun: `print([item[0] for item in (list(x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(list_num, lambda v, c=itertools.count(): v - next(c)))])` :-)

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments, and I edited my question to be more organized. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review your question again. Please correct your question because it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. These are the two conditions that i think you wish to achieve.

1. if `list[0] == 1` then remove that element.
2. if `list[i+1]-1 == list[i]` then remove `list[i+1]`

First of all in line 6 of your code there is an error, it should be `if ==` and not `if =`.The following code will achieve the above conditions.

```
numbers = int(input("Enter the limit for the list : "))

list_num = []

for i in range(0,numbers):
    list_num.append(int(input("list["+str(i)+"]: ")))

if list_num[0] == 1:
    list_num.remove(list_num[0])
try:
    for i in range(0,len(list_num)):
        if list_num[i] == list_num[i+1]-1:
            list_num.remove(list_num[i+1])
except:
    print list_num
```

Input: [1,2,7,8,13,20,21]

Output: [2,7,13,20]

Comment: `list[i+1]-1 == list[i]`. Nice catch.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete it by using keyword ***del***. Here is the example.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
del my_list[0] # 0 is the index
```

This will delete the first index of my_list. So the resultant list will be ***[2, 3, 4, 5]***

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) is the section from the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

There were several issues with your code including syntax, indentation and logic. I have formatted your code into a working manner. Good Luck.

```
numbers = input("input any numbers:")
list_num = list(numbers)

ret = []
for i,v in enumerate(list_num):
    if i == 0 and v == 1:
        continue
    if v == list_num[-1]:
        ret.append(v)
        break
    if v != list_num[i+1]:
        print v, list_num[i+1]
        ret.append(v)

print(ret)
```